# UserWarning: Previous unbuffered result was left incomplete warnings.warn("Previous unbuffered result was left incomplete")

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have used SQLalchemy to import some data to MySQL from a dataframe.
However, I got the error: UserWarning: Previous unbuffered result was left incomplete
warnings.warn("Previous unbuffered result was left incomplete") in the importing pocess.

code:

```
engine = 
      create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost:3308/tms_local', 
      echo=True)
with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():

   book_df.to_sql(name='temporary_table', con=conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
   result = conn.execution_options(stream_results=True).execute(text("SELECT `Publisher` FROM 
   temporary_table WHERE `Course Material Title` = 'StudyGuide';"))

   print(result)
```

Error:

```
    UserWarning: Previous unbuffered result was left incomplete
  warnings.warn("Previous unbuffered result was left incomplete")
<sqlalchemy.engine.result.BufferedRowResultProxy object at 0x000001BEBF0E4688>
2022-06-17 10:58:11,548 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

Comment: Tried ur method, some error says: AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'commit'

Comment: The same error still exists

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error. It is a warning. It is telling you that you have executed a query with streamed results and you have not consumed them by actually fetching the rows. Simply changing

```py
    print(result)
```

to

```py
    print(result.all())
```

makes the warning go away.